# Date() function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I have been researching and wrestling with this all day so I do not come here lightly. I have a piece of code that works perfectly in Chrome, I neither get it to work nor can I find any workaround for IE11.

I need to take an HTML text form field containing a `m/d/yyyy` pre-formatted date which was created using the `toLocaleDateString("en-US")` method (I've tried `mm/dd/yyyy` too) and convert it to a date object.

The attached snippet works fine in Chrome, neither the 3rd or 4th example will work in IE11 = "invalid date". However, if I substitute the daytext value with just a date string in quotes (e.g. "1/4/2015"), then it will work fine. You see that I am even forcing the `getElement` value to string just in case. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
<input type="text" id="datepic" name="datepic" value="4/8/2015" />
<script>
d = new Date();
tday = d.getTime()
//millidate = "1/4/2015";
millidate = new Date((2 * 86400000)+ 1*tday).toLocaleDateString("en-US"); 
document.getElementById('datepic').value = millidate;
daytext = document.getElementById("datepic").value;
alert(daytext)
daytext = String(daytext);
splt = daytext.split("/");
subs = daytext.substr(2,1);
text1 = "1/2/2015";
text2 = "1/"+2+"/2015";
text3 = "1/"+splt[1]+"/2015";
text4 = "1/"+subs+"/2015";
day1 = new Date(text1);
day2 = new Date(text2);
day3 = new Date(text3);
day4 = new Date(text4);
alert(day1);
alert(day2);
alert(day3);
alert(day4);
</script>
```

A more elaborate illustration of the problem -- uncomment the "millidate" value and comment the one below it. The former works -- the latter only in Chrome.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that all I really wanted to work was just `new Date(daytext)` -- this example was to help illustrate the problem in more detail.

Comment: if you forgot anything relevant to the question, edit it instead of commenting. And welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: "pre-formatted date which was created using the toLocaleDateString("en-US") method"

I'm getting quite strange results from that, at least in IE8. What is the literal value of daytext before you feed it into split?

Comment: do you get the expected values from splt[1] and subs? what is the current document mode that your IE11 is in?

Comment: I'm using a slider that moves from 1-365 then I'm multiplying that value by 86400000 to provide a date value in milliseconds, formatted using the toLocaleDateString method to populate the field. The date then manipulates a calendar to show relative payment scenarios.

Comment: Document mode is "Edge". the split and subs only work in Chrome -- I showed both examples to illustrate the strangeness of the problem. I can CREATE a string, but I cannot sub a string value evidently -- even when I force it into being a string() .

Comment: `console.log(daytext)` and `console.log(splt)` - what do you see? The issue is going to have something to do with something you're not posting here.

Comment: console.log(daytext): Error: Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference -- same for console.log(splt)

Comment: @RolandBouman gave me an idea -- I haven't yet tried formatting the field date otherwise than using  toLocaleDateString("en-US") - perhaps it is somehow related to that????? IE proves capable of taking a string in the m/d/yyyy format I'm using, but somehow it seems to think the date CREATED is NOT the same as a literal string -- despite what typeof thinks.

Comment: @iamattamai So what is the literal value of daytext? That really is the only question that needs answering before going any further.

Comment: The literal value of daytext today is "4/8/2015" verified as "string" by typeof -- you CAN substitute that for daytext as a literal string and it will work. As a reminder, ALL of this works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I added a more elaborate code example to the root question.